# I am having trouble on proving the this function $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.d

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Problem, Let $(X, d)$. Prove that $g(x) = d_X(x, a)$ is continuous from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ for a fixed $a \in X$.

Proof, Let $x_0$ be an arbitrary point in $X$. I want to show for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, for every $x \in X$, s.t. $d_X (x, x_0) < \delta \implies |(d_X (x, a) - d_X (a, x_0)|< \epsilon$. Clearly, whenever $x = x_0$, we can just set $\epsilon = 2 d_X(x_0, a)$. I don't exactly no what $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ should be when $x \neq x_0$.

Comment: That's not what you need to prove. It's $d_X (x, x_0) < \delta \implies |(d_X (x, a) - d_X (x_0, a)|< \epsilon$

Comment: @jjagmath isn't that equivalent since $|a-b| = |b-a|$, but I know that it's not the same as the definition

Comment: The problem is that you wrote $x$ instead of $a$.

Comment: Hey, I know that $||a| -|b|| \leq |a-b|$, but how can I prove that $|d_X (x,a) - d_X (x_0,a)| \leq d_X (x, x_0)$

Comment: @kobe The question that you linked isn't the same since it's set up incorrectly I think

Comment: A useful generalization is that if $\emptyset\ne A\subset X$ and if $f(x)=\inf \{d(x,a):a\in A\}$ then $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that for each $x_0$, and each $\epsilon \gt0$, there exists $\delta $ such that $$d(x, x_0)\lt\delta \implies \mid g(x)-g(x_0)\mid\lt\epsilon $$.

So, let $\epsilon \gt0$.  Choose $\delta =\epsilon$. Then $d(x_0,x)\lt\delta \implies\mid g(x_0)-g(x)\mid=\mid d(x_0,a)-d(x,a)\mid$.

But, by symmetry, and the triangle inequality, $d(x,x_0)\ge d(a,x)-d(a,x_0)$ and $d(x,x_0)\ge d(a,x_0)-d(a,x)$.  Thus $\mid d(x_0,a)-d(x,a)\mid\le d(x,x_0)\lt\epsilon $.